# Get a clean Youtube link from a NSString

Tags: objective-c, regex, ios7

I have stored in a NSString a youtube link but it's store in this way

```
<iframe width=""420"" height=""315"" src=""//www.youtube.com/watch?v=IeLZAYz5KpE"" frameborder=""0"" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

But, I would like to transform it or get or change to just the link like `//www.youtube.com/watch?v=IeLZAYz5KpE` to be able to display it in a video player within my app.

I don't have any idea how can I accomplish this.

**Update**
Code to test it this with the answer shown below..

```
NSString *searchedString = myURL;
NSRange   searchedRange = NSMakeRange(0, [searchedString length]);
NSString *pattern = @"\"\"(\\/\\/.*?)\"\"";
NSError  *error = nil;

NSRegularExpression* regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:pattern options:0 error:&error];
NSTextCheckingResult *match = [regex firstMatchInString:searchedString options:0 range: searchedRange];
NSLog(@"group1: %@", [searchedString substringWithRange:[match rangeAtIndex:1]]);
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get the youtube link with from that string, you can use this regex:

```
""(//.*?)""
```

**[Working demo](http://regex101.com/r/eN1hD7/1)**

[image]

```
MATCH 1
1.  [43-80] `//www.youtube.com/watch?v=IeLZAYz5KpE`
```

**Update:** to use my regex on objective-c you need to escape special characters as following:

```
\"\"(\\/\\/.*?)\"\"
```

Comment: this regular expression is only matching // in objective-c :(

Comment: @NorthBlast btw, can you try last attempt: `\"\"(\\/\\/.*?)\"\"`

Comment: @NorthBlast good news! Glad to help you. I've just updated and added the regex for objective-c. Btw, we can remove all the comments to clean the answer